# have already taken vs already taken

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Can simplify **have already <past participle>** to **already <past participle>**

e.g., are the following sentences both grammatical and idiomatic (with and without have)

> **I've already taken** the clothes into the house, as it is going to rain.
>
> **I already** taken the clothes into the house, as it is going to rain.

Comment: take, took, taken. I take, I took, I have taken, as any grammar book will tell you. And by the way, questions with modals are inverted> Can I Can we etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've already taken the clothes into the house, as it is going to rain. = correct/present perfect

I already taken the clothes into the house, as it is going to rain. = incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

@Bruce Murray and @william007
I agree with Bruce that 'I've already taken' is the correct one.   Further, I would think the comma before the dependent clause, 'as it is going to rain', should be removed.  (Here, the subordinating conjunction 'as' has made this originally independent clause subordinate upon the other.  When an independent clause precedes its dependent one, comma is disallowed; if the dependent clause comes first, put a comma). My suggestion is:
I've already taken the clothes into the house as it is going to rain.

Answer (score 0):

Correct: **I've already taken**. (I've= I have)

I have taken.- present perfect tense

I took.- simple past tense

In British English the present perfect tense is used with 'already'. ('I have already taken.')

In American English either the simple past tense or the present perfect tense is used with 'already'. ('**I already took.**' or 'I have already taken.'

present perfect tense- have/has + past participle

Comment: The American/British difference here is smaller than it's made out to be. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=already+took%3Aeng_us_2019%2Chave+already+taken%3Aeng_us_2019%2C+already+took%3Aeng_gb_2019%2Chave+already+taken%3Aeng_gb_2019%2C+&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: The present perfect tense is usually used with 'already' in British English. But the present perfect is less common in American English than in British English. The American  English speakers tend to use the simple past tense.